# How do I convert an integer to a list of indexes in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm pretty new to Lua, I'm trying to convert an integer into an array of indexes but cannot find a robust way to do this.
Here's two examples of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
Input: 0x11
Desired output: [0, 4]

Input: 0x29
Desired output: [0, 3, 5]
```

Comment: What's the algorithm used here? Can't find any correlation here

Comment: It's just simple bits. `0x1` = 0, `0x2` = 1, `0x4` = 2, `0x8` = 3, and I don't need to explain the rest.

Comment: Then you got both of your examples wrong. In that case, it would be `0x11` -> `[0, 4]` and `0x29` -> `[0, 3, 5]`.

Comment: Can you explain your conversion method to me?

Comment: Write 0x11 in binary: 10001. Now count right-to-left starting at 0, and put an element in the list each time it's a 1 bit. Now do the same for 0x29: 101001.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. Thanks for the clarification. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if you're on Lua 5.3 or newer:

```
local function oneBits(n)
    local i, rv = 0, {}
    while n ~= 0 do
        if n & 1 == 1 then
            table.insert(rv, i)
        end
        i = i + 1
        n = n >> 1
    end
    return rv
end
```

Comment: Works wonderfully. For prior versions, you can simply use the `bit32#band` and `bit32#rshift` methods instead.